# Use conditional statement to choose between different for loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

Depending on a certain condition, I want one of two different for loops to execute. So in the example below, I want console.log to return descending numbers if a > b, and ascending numbers if b > a. I was in no way surprised that this didn't work, but it gives you the idea of what I'm after.

```
for (if (a > b) {(i = 2; i > 0; i--)} else {(i = 0; i < 2; i++)} {
console.log(i);
};
```

Obviously I could work around this by having if-else select between two complete and separate loops each with their own console.log(i) code block, but in the case I'm dealing with, that will involve duplicating a huge amount of code.

Comment: what code would be duplicated a bunch? The body of the loop? If so, extract it to a separate function.

Comment: what you want to achieve? post some sample input and expected output. I think you're doing **over engineering** with simple task i.e getting ascending and descending numbers with `if` and `for`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 for(let i = a > b ? 2 : 0 ; a > b ? i > 0 : i < 2; a > b ? i-- : i++)
   console.log(i);
```

you have to move the condition into each expression. Or move the body in its own function:

```
 function body(i) {
   console.log(i);
 }

 if (a > b) {
   for(i = 2; i > 0; i--) body(i);
 } else {
   for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) body(i);
}
```

Or the functional way:

```
 const maybe = (condition, op) => arg => condition ? op(arg) : arg;
 const range = (start, end) => Array.from({ length: end - start }, (_, i) => start + i);

maybe(a > b, it => it.reverse())(range(0, 2)).forEach(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the body of the loop into a function, and on every iteration of both loops, call that function. Also note that `for` loop `}` end brackets should not have semicolons at the end:

```js
const a = 4;
const b = 5;

if (a > b) {
  for (let i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
    loop(i);
  }
} else {
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    loop(i);
  }
}
function loop(i) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](//jsfiddle.net/8ta176vo/)

```js
function choose(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    for (let i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

choose(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would turn it around like this: First do if statement then for loop.

```
if(a > b){
  for(let i = 2; i > 0; i--) console.log(i)
} else {
  for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try wrapping it in a function like this:

```js
function loop(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    for (i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }

}


loop(5,4);
loop(4,5);
```